# Driving multiple LEDs from microcontroller pin

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, led, resistors

I have a 12 V supply and I want to connect 4 LEDs to each pin of the microcontroller.
Voltage and current of each LED is 2.5 V and 20 mA.

When the output of the microcontroller becomes high the LEDs should be OFF, and when it is low the LEDs should be ON.

Can you please solve this?

Comment: the really dirty solution would be PNP or P-channel with a zener on the base to cut the excess voltage. Seriously why you can't simply turn the controller pin the other way?

Answer (score 2):

This should work. When the MCU output is high then Q2 turns on, shunting the current from R2 away from the base of Q1 and turning it off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGfLCo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Nice solution. Depending on the GPIO levels you could need a base resistor on Q2 to keep it in interdiction if it doesn't go all the way to ground (or maybe the 2n4401 is really hard to drive, I don't know the part)